# How to make a DLL for different VC compilers

Tags: c++, dll

I want to using one version of `VC++`, e.g. `VC++2003`, to make a DLL for my customers.

They may use `VC++2005, VC++2008Express, VC++2010Pro,...` and they may compile their projects with debug setting and release setting.

Can I make just one DLL for this purpose, or must I make several DLLs corresponding to all these possibilities?

Comment: It's pretty easy to use just one version if you stick to a pure C interface (or COM, if you prefer that).

Comment: You make one `.DLL` file that exports only flat C-style functions that do not use any compiler-dependent types/conventions/features. And one `.H` file for use in C/C++ compilers. Then, each compiler has its own means of importing the DLL into projects as needed, whether that is by creating a compiler-specific import LIB file, or providing specific code syntax to load/access the DLL function(s) directly.  Or, the user can simply call the Win32 `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` functions (or utilize their compiler's delay-load capabilities to call those functions automatically).

Comment: How about debug build and release build? Do I have to provide debug version .dll and release version .dll?

Answer (score 0):

I just create 2 DLL projects. One for release build and one for debug build. These 2 projects use multi-byte character set. 
To test, I create a EXE project using Unicode character set. Both debug and release build of the EXE project link to these 2 DLL without problem.

It's not what I already known. I have to update what I learned.

By the way, I use VC++2012 Express to test the above condition.